# includes in express 500 error - .html extension view engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have an express app where my views are set to HTML, but I'm actually using the ejs engine, to preserve the .html extension. It looks like this:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);
app.use(expressLayouts);
```

I want to use ejs includes in my templates. My folder structure is as follows:

`views/includes/include.html`

My include looks like this:

`<% include includes/include %>`

When setting the view engine to ejs (so for example `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`) the includes works as expected. But when using the view engine configuration that I have now (`app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);`) I get this:

> GET / 500 2.074 ms - 2580 Error: Could not find include include file.

In my view engine, do I need to explicitly set it to ejs, vs. the approach I'm taking now? How can I get includes to work with the .html extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the relevant line in the EJS source code is here:

https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/67ca0a80a5a68277774c693204ce49ef11bb84b4/lib/ejs.js#L112

That appends `.ejs` to the end of the filename for an `include` if it doesn't already have an extension. There doesn't seem to be any way to change that but you could explicitly add the `.html` extension to your `include`.

Comment: didn't think of that, but makes perfect sense now.